# How to abstract all datas using if else in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm first in prolog.

There are some family tree. So I want to abstract one's aunt list but, if I use if,else than only one aunt is abstracted. And, If i don't use condition, than mom also abstracted from predicates.

How can I continue in if, else?

```
female(mgrandmother).
female(mom).
female(sis).
female(aunt1).
female(aunt2).
male(mgrandfather).
male(dad).
male(bro).
male(uncle1).
male(uncle2).
parent(mom,sis).
parent(dad,sis).
parent(mom,bro).
parent(dad,bro).
parent(mgrandmother,aunt1).
parent(mgrandfather,aunt1).
parent(mgrandmother,aunt2).
parent(mgrandfather,aunt2).
parent(mgrandmother,mom).
parent(mgrandfather,mom).

aunt(X,Y):-
    parent(Z,Y), female(Z), parent(T, Z), male(T), repeat,parent(T,K),not(parent(K,Y))->X=K.

//If I printout all of aunts using like below

aunt(X,Y):-
    parent(Z,Y), female(Z), parent(T, Z), male(T), repeat,parent(T,K),not(parent(K,Y))->X=K.
//Than, It'll be print out also mom
```

Comment: You probably should not use "if-else" in the first place. You can for example use `dif` to add a constraint to prevent yielding the mother of that person.

Comment: Your English is barely understandable, which is not a crime, but it makes it difficult to follow.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I see. So I edit code like this. aunt(X,Y):-
    parent(Z,Y), female(Z), parent(T, Z), male(T),parent(T,K), dif(K,Z)->X=K.
But there are yet problem left only aunt1 is printed out thank you

Comment: @User9213 Sorry for you. I'm not good at english. I do the effort for learning english more. Really sorry

Comment: @YJS: no just `dif(K, Z)`, you can also use `X` directly in the body of your predicate.

Comment: @YJS do not feel sorry for me, just keep on learning.

Comment: @User9213 they probably meant "apologies to you". :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh I learned one more thing in here. Thank you

Comment: @WillNess Yep. I mean it. b

Comment: @YJS use more words, and play with google translate more, to make sure there's less chance for misunderstandings. :)

Comment: @WillNess Thank you. I'll make the most of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you make it more complicated than it is, by writing all logic in the `aunt/2` predicate. Instead of trying to solve the entire problem in a single predicate, it is typically beneficial to write several small *reusable* predicates. It makes predicates easier to understand, and furthermore you can reuse these components in other predicates.

For example we can implement a `slibing/2` predicate:

```
sibling(S1, S2) :-
    parent(P, S1),
    male(P),
    parent(P, S2),
    dif(S1, S2).
```

here the `dif/2` will prevent that the slibings `S1` and `S2` are the same person. This thus means that we will not need to worry about that scenario in all use cases of the `slibing/2` predicate. We here use `male/1` to prevent that two siblings will be yielded two times: one time for the mother relation, and one time for the father relation.

Perhaps you want to later refine the above predicate, since this predicate will succeed if `S1` and `S2` are *half-siblings* given they have the father in common.

Next we can implement a `sister/2` predicate for example:

```
sister(S, C) :-
    sibling(S, C),
    female(S).
```

Now our `aunt/2` is simply the sister of the parent of a person, so:

```
aunt(A, C):-
    parent(P, C),
    sister(A, P).
```

Not only are the predicates way simpler, we now have two extra predicates. Furthermore if the logic of `sibling/2` turns out to have some problems, we can fix it at that specific level, and all callers of `sibling/2` will be fixed as well.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I don't comment on it, But I need to print out only aunts, and no false. But if I do like your code, it returns like this.
?- aunt(X,sis).
X = aunt1 ;
X = aunt2 ;
false.

Comment: @YJS: `false` simply means that it can not find any other results. It is not part of the result set, and it is not printed to the `stdout`, but to the `stderr`.

Comment: Oh it must be good that not stdout but stderr. I understand what you mean. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean "extract", not "abstract".

Why are you using `repeat`? Did someone tell you to use it or you think you have to? Same with `->`: you certainly don't need it here.

Here is one way to define what you want:

```
aunt(Aunt, Child) :-
    parent(Parent, Child),
    siblings(Parent, Aunt),
    female(Aunt).

siblings(C1, C2) :-
    dif(C1, C2),
    parent(P, C1),
    parent(P, C2).
```

The only addition to what you have is `dif/2` in the definition of `siblings/2`, so that a person is not a sibling to themselves.

You will get answers on backtracking (you don't need to use `repeat` !):

```
?- aunt(Aunt, Child).
Aunt = aunt1,
Child = sis ;
Aunt = aunt2,
Child = sis ;
Aunt = aunt1,
Child = sis ;
Aunt = aunt2,
Child = sis ;
Aunt = aunt1,
Child = bro ;
Aunt = aunt2,
Child = bro ;
Aunt = aunt1,
Child = bro ;
Aunt = aunt2,
Child = bro ;
false.
```

The easy way to show all solutions and avoid duplicates is `setof/3`:

```
?- setof(Aunt-Child, aunt(Aunt, Child), Results).
Results = [aunt1-bro, aunt1-sis, aunt2-bro, aunt2-sis].
```

Comment: Really thank you. But can I remove 'false' which printed out all of aunts and when predicates are finished?